# trying to remove the date from all thr rows of my table

Tags: javascript

with javascript, i am trying to get rid of all the dates and only keeping the time from all my rows of the table

here is the screenshot i am taking about

[image: 1]

i cannot use the id or class of the td because its dynamic.

i am trying to ynderstand how can i loop it over to make it work

here is my piece of code i have

```
var header = document.getElementsByClassName('flightData1')[0];
var dateField = ?
```

also trying to add some condition here that if the records are not in todays date, remove those rows

here is my html

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" id="iFlightTable" class="cellpadding3 styled-table"> 
 <tbody> 
  <tr class="flightData1" id="AS 2224_2023-02-09T21:17:00_Anchorage_row"> 
   <td id="Alaska Air">  Alaska</td> 
   <td> 2224</td> 
   <td> Anchorage</td> 
   <td id="1676006220000"> 9:17P&nbsp;02-09-23</td> 
   <td> <font class="default"> On Time </font> </td> <!-- --> 
   <td id="AS 2224_2023-02-09T21:17:00_bags"> </td> 
   <td id="AS 2224_2023-02-09T21:17:00_gate">2A</td> 
   <td>&nbsp;</td> 
   <td>&nbsp;</td> 
   <td>&nbsp;</td>  
  </tr> 
  <tr class="flightData2" id="AS 657_2023-02-09T16:35:00_Las Vegas_row"> 
   <td id="Alaska Air">  Alaska</td> 
   <td> 657</td> 
   <td> Las Vegas</td> 
   <td id="1675989300000"> 4:35P&nbsp;02-09-23</td> 
   <td> <font class="default"> On Time </font> </td> <!-- --> 
   <td id="AS 657_2023-02-09T16:35:00_bags"> </td> 
   <td id="AS 657_2023-02-09T16:35:00_gate">1</td> 
   <td>&nbsp;</td> 
   <td>&nbsp;</td> 
   <td>&nbsp;</td>  
  </tr> </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Please post your HTML in the question as text, not an image.

Comment: Please post code, screenshots (pictures) of code are actively harmful and of no use whatsoever. Please review the "*[ask]*" guidelines, especially the emphasised (and important) "**DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc.**" (emphasis in the original).

Answer (score 0):

```js
    let dateFields = document.querySelectorAll('#iFlightTable tr td:nth-child(4)');

    dateFields.forEach( field => {
      field.innerText = field.innerText.split(/\s/)[0];
    });
```

```html
    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" id="iFlightTable" class="cellpadding3 styled-table"> 
     <tbody> 
      <tr class="flightData1" id="AS 2224_2023-02-09T21:17:00_Anchorage_row"> 
       <td id="Alaska Air">  Alaska</td> 
       <td> 2224</td> 
       <td> Anchorage</td> 
       <td id="1676006220000"> 9:17P&nbsp;02-09-23</td> 
       <td> <font class="default"> On Time </font> </td> <!-- --> 
       <td id="AS 2224_2023-02-09T21:17:00_bags"> </td> 
       <td id="AS 2224_2023-02-09T21:17:00_gate">2A</td> 
       <td>&nbsp;</td> 
       <td>&nbsp;</td> 
       <td>&nbsp;</td>  
      </tr> 
      <tr class="flightData2" id="AS 657_2023-02-09T16:35:00_Las Vegas_row"> 
       <td id="Alaska Air">  Alaska</td> 
       <td> 657</td> 
       <td> Las Vegas</td> 
       <td id="1675989300000"> 4:35P&nbsp;02-09-23</td> 
       <td> <font class="default"> On Time </font> </td> <!-- --> 
       <td id="AS 657_2023-02-09T16:35:00_bags"> </td> 
       <td id="AS 657_2023-02-09T16:35:00_gate">1</td> 
       <td>&nbsp;</td> 
       <td>&nbsp;</td> 
       <td>&nbsp;</td>  
      </tr> </tbody>
```

Comment: between that is in console, how i add in my table to replace the  date with time, but before this should i do, i want to remove rows which does not have today's date and replace with no data dound

Comment: @Rodnee: Ideally, in the code that generates your HTML. Failing that, instead of logging it in the console, set the field's innerText or innerHTML.  The "before this i should do" bit is a new question, but this is getting very close to getting people to write code for you rather than helping you debug a problem.

Comment: @cHao bye bye it means so why you noot trigger your answer somewhere else